# Retrieve token in angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, post, reset-password

I Have to reset password form that sends a link `http://localhost:4200/reset/token.`
I want to retrieve the token and verify it in the angular application.

**Thie code below sends a link with a token**

```
function(done) {
        Usermodel.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user){
            if(!user){
                return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'error', detail: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired'}]});
            }

            if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm){
                user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err){
                    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                    user.save(function(err){
                        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                            done(err, user);
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'error', detail: 'Password do not match'}]});
            }
        });
    },

});
```

What would be the best solution to implement this, because if a user can access the change password page without a token verification it would create a security vunlerabilty